# Using .htacces to mask a URL, make the subdomain the root domain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, dns, url-masking, domain-masking

I currently have a cms which builds microsites in subdirectories. So the mainsite is the root and each subsite is in a subdirectory.

eg root = www.mainsite.org

microsite = www.mainsite.org/microsite

I'm currently buying and parking domains on the mainsite's hosting space. I have it set up so that when the user types in www.microsite.org they are redirected to www.mainsite.org/microsite using the following in my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^microsite.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^microsite.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mainsite\.org\/microsite" [R=301,L]
```

can I also mask the url so that www.mainsite.com/microsite appears in the url bar as www.microsite.org - allowing each of the microsites to retain individual identity. I own the domains for each of the microsites

I don't necessarily need a blanket rule, I'm happy to add new code for each microsite.

By the way, I don't really understand htaccess editing - am pretty new to it, so specific answers would be hugely appreciated. I've searched for answers, but don't think I've found any that are masking the root in this way - most seem to hide the subdirectories.

thanks

Comment: Could you use CNAME record inside you DNS for that purpose?

Comment: problem is the cname only seems to accept it all with the www. - I'd like it to work with or without.